# Fourier series and tempered distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

This is an problem from Folland's Real Analysis

Let $E_k(x)=e^{2\pi k \cdot x}$. 
If $g:\mathbb Z^n\to \mathbb C $ satisfies $|g(k)|\leq C(1+|k|)^N$ for some $C, N>0$, then the series $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}g(k)E_k$  converges in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb T^n)$ to a distribution $F$ that satisfies $\hat F=g$. It also converges in  $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n)$ to a tempered distribution $G=P'F$ such that $\tau_kG=G$ for all $k$.

Here  the periodization map $P$ is defined as $Pf=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}\tau_k\phi$. I managed to show that $P$ is continuous from $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ to $C^\infty (\mathbb T^n)$. Therefore $P'$ is also continuous.

But I am having trouble to show the convergence of the series $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}g(k)E_k$    in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb T^n)$ .

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $\mathcal D'(\mathbb T^n)$ are the continuous linear functionals on $C^\infty(\Bbb{T}^n)$ the $\Bbb{Z}^n$-periodic smooth functions. The Fourier coefficients of those are fast decreasing and $|\langle F,\phi \rangle|=|\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}g(k) \hat{\phi}(k)| \le C\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}(1+|2\pi k|)^{N}|\hat{\phi}(k)| \le B_N C \sum_{\alpha \le N}\|D^\alpha \phi\|_2$ (Cauchy Schwarz)

Comment: @reuns Can you explain how did you get the last inequality?

Comment: With $n=2$ and $N \ge 3$ then $\sum_{(a,b) \ne (0,0)} (|a|+|b|)^N |\hat{\phi}(a,b)| \le C\sum_{(a,b) \ne (0,0)} (|a|^N+|b|^N) |\hat{\phi}(a,b)|$ $\le C\sqrt{\sum_{(a,b) \ne (0,0)} (a^{2N}+b^{2N}) |\hat{\phi}(a,b)|^2} \sqrt{\sum_{(a,b) \ne (0,0)} \frac{1}{a^{2N}+b^{2N}}}= C' \sqrt{\| D_x^N \phi\|_2^2+\| D_y^N \phi\|_2^2}$ $ \le C''(\| D_x^N \phi\|_2+\| D_y^N \phi\|_2)$

Comment: Why does this imply F is continuous?

Comment: ??? That for some $N,C, |\langle F,\phi \rangle| \le C \sum_{\alpha \le N}\|D^\alpha \phi\|_2$ is the definition of  "$F$ is a continuous linear functional on $C^\infty(\Bbb{T}^n)$", given the definition of the topology on $C^\infty(\Bbb{T}^n)$.

Comment: Shouldn't we use uniform norm instead of L$^2$?

Comment: $\|\phi\|_\infty \le c (\|\phi\|_{L^2}+\|\phi'\|_{L^2})$, the topology on $C^\infty(\Bbb{T}^n)$ is for some $p \ge 1$ the $L^p$-convergence of all the derivatives .